# Split function in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to split the address into two columns as streetno and streetname, say for ex select address1 from customer

address for ex-look like

2719 STONE CREEK DR
and store them into street no as 2719 and streetname as  STONE CREEK DR.

select regexp_extract(address1,'(?<=\s).*',0),'|',splitaddress1, '[\ ]')[0] from table;

Sample data:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSdEV.png)

[image]

Expected output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPqdl.png)

[image]

But when I run the above query, I am getting none in spark but results in Hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly:

```
>>> qry = """
... select split(addressl, '\\\s+')[0] as streetnumber,
...        regexp_replace(addressl, '^\\\d+\\\s+', '') as streetname
... from table"""
>>> spark.sql(qry).show()
+------------+-----------------+
|streetnumber|       streetname|
+------------+-----------------+
|         100|HORACE GREELEY RD|
|          55|    School Street|
|        2893|       MASHIE CIR|
|        1200|         JEWEL DR|
|         201|       W RIVER RD|
+------------+-----------------+
```